# using Gson to accept specific class to a method, but implementation is unknown

Tags: java, gson

Let's say there is an interface with a method:

```
public void receiveResult(ApiResponse apiResponse);
```

ApiResponse is subclassed by other "response" classes.

Now there is also a Runnable which, somewhere in the code, executes:

```
interfaceCallback.receiveResult(new Gson().fromJson(someHttpResponse, ???);
```

the constructor for the Runnable needs to be able to take any class object:

```
new MyRunnable(SomeResponse.class); (SomeResponse is a subclass of ApiResponse)
new MyRunnable(AnotherResponse.class); (AnotherResponse is a subclass of ApiResponse)
```

Is this possible? I've been trying to write the constructor as follows:

```
public MyRunnable(Class<? extends ApiResponse> passedClass) {
// set fields
}
```

but when I try to instantiate MyRunnable, I cannot do the following:

```
new MyRunnable(SomeResponse.class);
new MyRunnable(AnotherResponse.class);
```

I hope this makes sense.

edit:

```
public interface Callback {
    public void receiveResult(ApiResponse apiResponseClass);
}

public class RunnableRequest {
     public <T extends ApiResponse> RunnableRequest(Class<T> passedApiResponseClass, Callback callback) {
          this.passedApiResponseClass = passedApiResponseClass;
          this.callback = callback;
     }

     @Override
     public void run() {
          callback.receiveResult(new Gson().fromJson(httpResponseString,    passedApiResponseClass));
     }
}
```

The error is here (another class):

```
new RunnableApiGetRequest(MyResponse.class, callback);
```

error:
cannot be applied to
expected
Class
actual
MyResponse.class

EDIT #3:

```
// I am not sure how to define the object that is passed here.
static RunnableRequest createRequestRunnable(???, Callback callback) {
    return new RunnableRequest(???, callback);
}

public class RunnableRequest implements Runnable {
    // Here is where I am not sure exactly how to pass, for example, SystemStatusResponse.class OR ApiResponse.class
    // OR SomeOtherResponse.class OR Whatever.class
    public <T extends ApiResponse> RunnableRequest(???, Callback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
        this.apiResponse = apiResponse;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String exampleResponse = "{\"result\":\"Success\",\"message\":\"Hello World\",\"error\":\"0\"}";
        // not sure what to put here. normally I can just pass SystemStatusResponse.class or ApiResponse.class
        // or any other subclass of ApiResponse 
        callback.apiRequestProcessFinished(new Gson().fromJson(getResponseString(exampleResponse), ???));

    }
}

public interface Callback {
    // I am not 100% sure on how to define this interface because the "apiResponse" should of the type
    // that was originally passed to the method "createRequestRunnable"
    public void apiRequestProcessFinished(ApiResponse apiResponse);
}

// sample Gson response class
public class ApiResponse {
    private String message;
    private String result;
    private String error;

    public final String getMessage() { return message; }
    public final String getError() { return error; }
    public final String getResult() { return result; }
}

// sample Gson response class which subclasses ApiResponse
public class SystemStatusResponse extends ApiResponse {
    private String status;
    private String uptime;
    private String lastdowntime;
    public String getStatus() { return status; }
    public String getUptime() { return uptime; }
    public String getLastDownTime() { return lastdowntime; }
}
```

Comment: Why you can't do that? What it says? It works as expected. No error.

Comment: i will edit original question

Comment: where `RunnableApiGetRequest` class is defiend. It would be better if you can post the code in your question itself as EDIT section rather than in a comment.

Comment: Please share a minimal testable code. How `passedApiResponseClass` is declared in  `RunnableRequest` class.

Comment: Under EDIT#3 I have posted code. I have added a few comments and some ??? where I am not sure how to do what I'm trying to do.

What I want to do is be able to pass any "Something.class" so Gson can parse it and then have the Callback interface also use that class as the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help you. Make the class or interface *Generic* rather than a method as shown below:

```
public class RunnableRequest<T extends ApiResponse> implements Runnable {
    private Class<T> apiResponse;
    private Callback<T> callback;

    public RunnableRequest(Class<T> apiResponse, Callback<T> callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
        this.apiResponse = apiResponse;            
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String exampleResponse = "{\"result\":\"Success\",\"message\":\"Hello World\",\"error\":\"0\"}";            
        callback.apiRequestProcessFinished(new Gson().fromJson(exampleResponse, apiResponse));

    }
}

public interface Callback<T extends ApiResponse> {       
    public void apiRequestProcessFinished(T apiResponse);
}

static <T extends ApiResponse> RunnableRequest<T> createRequestRunnable(Class<T> apiResponse,
        Callback<T> callback) {
    return new RunnableRequest<T>(apiResponse, callback);
}
```

Comment: Let me try this out and I shall report back. Thank you by the way for your help so far.

Comment: Braj,

This worked perfectly. I looked at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html

for help regarding generics but I don't think I understood correctly.

I also looked at the AsyncTask.java class from the Android library and they use Generics I think, but instead of T they use Generics called Result, Params, and Progress.

Is there another source besides the oracle site I linked and the AsyncTask.java from Android to give me some examples (via baby steps) because I would really like to know how to use Generics since I think I can use them in several places (i.e. above).

Comment: Braj, one last question if you don't mind.

since the header for the interface is:
 public interface Callback<T extends ApiResponse>

when I implement Callback, via Something implements Callback

is it possible for the implemented interface method to be the T passed?

In other words, if the ApiResponse subclass is called SystemStatusInfo, is it possible to have the callback method parameters be (SystemStatusInfo apiResponse) or will I have to cast from ApiResponse to the subclass?

Again, thanks a lot mate.

EDIT: nvm. just add <UserGetInfoResponse> after the "implements InterfaceName" thanks!